# php_SOAP.DLL where to download?

Tags: php, dll, soap

found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640036/where-do-i-download-the-php-soap-extension-for-windows

But does not work any more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.3.10-Win32-VC9-x86.zip

That is assuming you want PHP 5.3 thread-safe compiled with VC9.

Answer (score 0):

For windows you only need uncomment the extension in your php.ini

```
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
; ...
; ...
extension=php_soap.dll
```

Enjoy!